# C# Windows Service not clearing memory from the previous run

Tags: c#, windows, loops, memory, service

I am new to Windows Services and C#. I have this windows service which should read from a table and post the details via a JSON to an external interface. Once we get the successful return back from the interface, we update a flag on our end to indicate that the record has been successfully processed.

The problem I am running into right now is, the first run when the timer is initiated, it correctly picks up the records which do not have the flag set. Once the records are processed, the timer sleeps for the specified interval and then initiates the next run. Ideally in this run, the records which were previously processed should not have been picked up, but the same records get picked again which makes me believe that the memory isn't getting cleared from the previous run.

My Onstart code is as follows.

```cs
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        log.Info("Starting the service");
        
        T = new System.Timers.Timer();
        T.Enabled = true;
        T.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedHandler);
        T.Interval = scheduledTime;
    }
    
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.info(e.message());
    }
}
```

The OnElapsedHandler code is as follows.

```cs
private void OnElapsedHandler(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //String path = @"E:\Program\JobRun.txt";
    // Check the local time
    ESTBranches = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EST"].ToString().Split(',');
    CSTBranches = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CST"].ToString().Split(',');
    MSTBranches = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MST"].ToString().Split(',');
    PSTBranches = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PST"].ToString().Split(',');

    DateTime currentDateTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    int hour = Int32.Parse(currentDateTimeUTC.ToString("HH"));

    List<Model_Parts> lstParts = new List<Model_Parts>();
    lstParts = mwQ.GetPartsQueue(); // Get list of unprocessed parts in MW from MB

    Auth auth = new Auth();

    double elapsedMillisecs = ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - auth.GenerateTime)).TotalMilliseconds;

    if (elapsedMillisecs > 3600000 || auth.AuthToken.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        sfsOps.GetSFSAccessToken();
    }

    sfsOps.BuildPartsJSON("Create", lstParts);
}
```

lstParts gets populated with the records whose flag is not set. This gets processed correctly during the very first run when the service is initiated. In the subsequent runs, lstParts still has the same details from the previous run. This is creating duplicates in the target system.

Can anyone please help me understand why the previous run values are not getting flushed?

Comment: Are you sure problem is in the code you posted? What about `mwQ.GetPartsQueue();`? Can it be that method result gets cached so you alway get the very same answer?

Comment: `lstParts = mwQ.GetPartsQueue();` problem is presumably hidden somewhere here but not actually in the code you show. A guess. This looks like a queue operation many queue system want at some point an acknowledgement that things are taken from the queue and handled correctly. If you don't acknowledge things stay on the queue stuff gets rejected and maybe read again in the future. In any case we are missing details about that queue.

Comment: services are long lived, there is no automatic "memory clear". If you have problems it is likely inside the `GetPartsQueue` part that does some caching or similar. Since this method is not shown the question is not really possible to answer.

Comment: Probably not the solution, but put "T.Enabled = false;" at beginning of OnElapsedHandler, and "T.Enabled = true;" before leaving.

Comment: Thanks all for taking a quick look at this. The problem indeed was in GetPartsQueue as Marco and Ralf suggested. The scope of a variable which held the result that was being returned was at the class level. When the GetPartsQueue method was being called, this value was not getting initialized due to its higher scope. Once I reduced the scope of the variable, the issue was resolved. Thanks once again for providing the pointers.